# How to setFocus on Apache Royale Jewel Button?

Tags: button, focus, apache-royale

All is in the title...
I would like to trigger at application startup this definition in css :

```
.jewel.button:focus
```

But I don't see any setFocus or focus property on j:Button
Could you tell me how to do ? Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: This is no longer right. Recently SetFocus bead was removed and StyledUIBase got "setFocus" method. Use it instead of the code below.**

Use the Basic bead `SetFocus`recenlty added:

```
<j:Button text="Hello!" emphasis="secondary">
    <j:beads>
        <js:SetFocus enableFocus="true"/>
    </j:beads>
</j:Button>
```